# webscraping specify information to scrape

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape the names of each of the people on the site https://eumostwanted.eu/
When I try to scrape the class "field content" it brings back a bunch of information, how can I use beautiful soup to narrow it down/add more criteria to what I am selecting? How can I scrape using more than one identifier? Thank you in advance

```
code:

info = requests.get("https://eumostwanted.eu/")
text = info.text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")

result = soup.select('.field-content')
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but I guess you need the data for each person separated. You could iterate over each 'container' of a person and get it's data:

```
info = requests.get("https://eumostwanted.eu/")
text = info.text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")

people = soup.select('div.views-row')
for person in people:
    result = person.select('.field-content')
    for attr in result:
        print(attr.text.strip())
```